# How would one export the last three lines of emails in a folder from Outlook to Excell?

Tags: excel, email, outlook, export

I'm trying to export the last three lines (signature lines) from a folder of emails that I have in outlook. Basically, my organization got a lot (1300 or so) of emails that are the variations on the same message but always end with customized signatures from our constituents. Here's an example:

> Dear Assembly Member XXXX:
>
> I am adamantly opposed to any plan to move ahead with massive air
>   rights -------------------- -------------
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------- --------------------------------- -------------- --- --------------- -------------------------------- ------------------ ------------ ------------- ----------------------- overdevelopment in our neighborhood in the future.
>
> We have ------- ----- ---- -------- -------------
>   -------------------------- ------- --------- --------------- ----------------- ------------------------ --------------- ---------- --------- --------------- ------------------ ----------- --- neighborhood.
>
> And nearly three years after the State Legislature voted to allow the
>   transfer of millions of square feet of “air rights” -----------------
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- enable overdevelopment in our neighborhood.
>
> This mega-development should NOT be approved until and unless these
>   issues are addressed. The ------- ----- --- -- -------------- ------- 
>   - - ---------------------------------- ----------- ---------- ---------------------- ------- ---------- --- - ---- communities are ignored.
>
> Constituent Name
>
> XXX Streetname St.
>
> NY, NY 99999

What I'd like to do is take those last three lines that contain the person's name and address and export each line into a column in an excel dock, with a separate column for the sender's email address. What would be the easiest way for me to go about doing this? Or is there not really a way?

Thanks a bunch!

-Julian

Comment: Yes, you can use vba to capture the Body of the email, then split the email based on the new line character present into an array. Then you would select the last three entries in the array for each email.

Comment: Great, thank you. Is there a walkthrough I could view somewhere of how to do this? I'm a bit new to the whole outlook/vba system.